# EF Eager Loading vs Lazy Loading, performance issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having some performance issues at the moment. I have 27 rows of data, if I turn on **Lazy loading** and make sure there are no navigational properties, when I do a request I can see this SQL generated:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[ExternalId] AS [ExternalId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
[Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
[Extent1].[Address3] AS [Address3], 
[Extent1].[Address4] AS [Address4], 
[Extent1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
[Extent1].[CollectionPointContact] AS [CollectionPointContact], 
[Extent1].[CollectionPointTelephone] AS [CollectionPointTelephone], 
[Extent1].[CollectionPointFax] AS [CollectionPointFax], 
[Extent1].[CollectionPointEmail] AS [CollectionPointEmail], 
[Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
[Extent1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
[Extent1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
[Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified]
FROM [dbo].[Centers] AS [Extent1]
```

It tells me that it executed in 47ms, in PostMan it takes circa 300ms to execute. That seems to be a long time, but that isn't the issue. The model looks like this:

```
public class Archive
{
    [Required, MaxLength(128)] public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(128)] public string ModifiedById { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}

public class Center : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(150)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address4 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)] public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string CollectionPointContact { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointTelephone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointFax { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string CollectionPointEmail { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IList<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}
```

And the 2 navigational properties that must be included are **Company** and **Collections**, their models look like this:

```
public class Company : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Theme { get; set; }

    public IList<User> Members { get; set; }
    public IList<Center> Centers { get; set; }
}

public class Collection : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CenterId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)] public string Reference { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string CustomerBusinessName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="Date")] public DateTime PlannedCollectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CollectedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedBySignature { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string CollectedBy { get; set; }
    public string CollectedBySignature { get; set; }

    public CollectionStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

They don't need any navigation properties, so the buck stops there (or should at least).
If I use **Eager Loading** and run through PostMan I can see that the same request takes 355ms within VS and in PostMan it takes around 1300ms (first load always seems to be over 2000ms).
The SQL generated looks like this:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[ExternalId] AS [ExternalId], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
[Project1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
[Project1].[Address3] AS [Address3], 
[Project1].[Address4] AS [Address4], 
[Project1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
[Project1].[CollectionPointContact] AS [CollectionPointContact], 
[Project1].[CollectionPointTelephone] AS [CollectionPointTelephone], 
[Project1].[CollectionPointFax] AS [CollectionPointFax], 
[Project1].[CollectionPointEmail] AS [CollectionPointEmail], 
[Project1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
[Project1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
[Project1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
[Project1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
[Project1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project1].[Logo] AS [Logo], 
[Project1].[Theme] AS [Theme], 
[Project1].[CreatedById1] AS [CreatedById1], 
[Project1].[ModifiedById1] AS [ModifiedById1], 
[Project1].[DateCreated1] AS [DateCreated1], 
[Project1].[DateModified1] AS [DateModified1], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
[Project1].[CenterId] AS [CenterId], 
[Project1].[Reference] AS [Reference], 
[Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1], 
[Project1].[CustomerReference] AS [CustomerReference], 
[Project1].[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], 
[Project1].[CustomerBusinessName] AS [CustomerBusinessName], 
[Project1].[SupplierName] AS [SupplierName], 
[Project1].[PlannedCollectionDate] AS [PlannedCollectionDate], 
[Project1].[DeliveredDate] AS [DeliveredDate], 
[Project1].[CollectedDate] AS [CollectedDate], 
[Project1].[ReceivedBy] AS [ReceivedBy], 
[Project1].[ReceivedBySignature] AS [ReceivedBySignature], 
[Project1].[CollectedBy] AS [CollectedBy], 
[Project1].[CollectedBySignature] AS [CollectedBySignature], 
[Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Project1].[CreatedById2] AS [CreatedById2], 
[Project1].[ModifiedById2] AS [ModifiedById2], 
[Project1].[DateCreated2] AS [DateCreated2], 
[Project1].[DateModified2] AS [DateModified2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ExternalId] AS [ExternalId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
    [Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
    [Extent1].[Address3] AS [Address3], 
    [Extent1].[Address4] AS [Address4], 
    [Extent1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
    [Extent1].[CollectionPointContact] AS [CollectionPointContact], 
    [Extent1].[CollectionPointTelephone] AS [CollectionPointTelephone], 
    [Extent1].[CollectionPointFax] AS [CollectionPointFax], 
    [Extent1].[CollectionPointEmail] AS [CollectionPointEmail], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
    [Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
    [Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent2].[Logo] AS [Logo], 
    [Extent2].[Theme] AS [Theme], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById1], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById1], 
    [Extent2].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated1], 
    [Extent2].[DateModified] AS [DateModified1], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], 
    [Extent3].[CenterId] AS [CenterId], 
    [Extent3].[Reference] AS [Reference], 
    [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description1], 
    [Extent3].[CustomerReference] AS [CustomerReference], 
    [Extent3].[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], 
    [Extent3].[CustomerBusinessName] AS [CustomerBusinessName], 
    [Extent3].[SupplierName] AS [SupplierName], 
    [Extent3].[PlannedCollectionDate] AS [PlannedCollectionDate], 
    [Extent3].[DeliveredDate] AS [DeliveredDate], 
    [Extent3].[CollectedDate] AS [CollectedDate], 
    [Extent3].[ReceivedBy] AS [ReceivedBy], 
    [Extent3].[ReceivedBySignature] AS [ReceivedBySignature], 
    [Extent3].[CollectedBy] AS [CollectedBy], 
    [Extent3].[CollectedBySignature] AS [CollectedBySignature], 
    [Extent3].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent3].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById2], 
    [Extent3].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById2], 
    [Extent3].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated2], 
    [Extent3].[DateModified] AS [DateModified2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Centers] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CompanyId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Collections] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[CenterId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[Id1] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

This seems a bit odd to me, but I will assume that EF knows what it is doing. 
Anyway, adding the Collections and the Company makes the request average around 1 second, but on the first load it is usually 2s+.

If I then disable **Eager loading** and switch to **Lazy loading** and make sure both **Company** and **Collections** are vitual properties there are some differences.
The main difference is that now all **Collections** and **Companies** are loaded as separate SQL statements, which obviously increases the load time.
In PostMan, the first load time is over 4s, every request after that is about 3s.
So in this case, **Eager loading** is superior, but still pulling in 271 records in a second seems like a long time. I would like to increase the performance a lot more than this. 
So, can someone come up with some suggestion(s) on how I can address this issue?

Comment: With such a small amount of data this must be an indexing problem. Analyze the query execution plan of the SQL query.

Comment: how do you do that?