# Entity Framework, stored procedures and navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a POCO class that has 2 navigation properties which looks like this:

```
public class Center : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(150)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string Address4 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)] public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string CollectionPointContact { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointTelephone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CollectionPointFax { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string CollectionPointEmail { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IList<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}

public class Company : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Theme { get; set; }

    public IList<User> Members { get; set; }
    public IList<Center> Centers { get; set; }
}

public class Collection : Archive
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CenterId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)] public string Reference { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)] public string Description { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)] public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string CustomerBusinessName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)] public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="Date")] public DateTime PlannedCollectionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CollectedDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedBySignature { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)] public string CollectedBy { get; set; }
    public string CollectedBySignature { get; set; }

    public CollectionStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

At first I was using the default lazy loading to populate the properties, but it was taking 2s+ to load 300 rows of data (including the properties) which is just unacceptable.

I decided to switch to eager loading because I know with eager loading the SQL generated will use joins, so, in theory would be faster. This was not the case, it was still taking around 2s to complete.

So my next task was to try and use a stored procedure. In my repository class I wrote a generic method:

```
internal class Repository<T> : IDisposable, IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        _context = context;
        _dbEntitySet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IList<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        if (parameters == null)
            return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>($"exec { storedProcedureName }").ToList();
        else
            return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>($"exec { storedProcedureName } @{ parameters[0].ParameterName }").ToList();
    }
}
```

While this seems to be faster (still at 1s which I still think is excessive), it is not pulling in my navigation properties.

I found an article explaining [how to do it if you are not using generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but I would like to be able to do it for any navigation property.

I thought about using reflection, but that will just add to the overhead cost.

Has anyone come across this and solved the issue or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Without the code of how you originally loaded data, there is no way to determine if it was done in a performant manner.  I very rarely recommend lazy loading as it's generally a performance nightmare.  Calling a stored procedure will never auto populate your navigation properties because EF is not generating the query.  If you want to continue down the sproc road let me know (i actually just switched a very advanced query I was using to a proc because EF was not generating performant queries for me).

Comment: In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41664805/861716) you told that you're dealing with a very small amount of data. First of all, you have to analyze proper usage of indexes first before trying to optimize what can't be optimized if the foundation isn't solid. Use Sql Server Management Studio to execute the query, with "include actual query plan", and look for index hints. *Then* think about the data you really need. Do you really need to bring the full records to the client? *Projections* tend to improve performance considerably.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine eager and lazy loading by using virtual properties for lazy support and call the Include method on your IQeryable to eager load related entities. You can improve the performance by writing no tracking queries https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203 (changes will not be detected by ef)